# errors in java code, i don't undersatnd why

Tags: java, file, passwords, ioexception, filewriter

i have 4 errors in this code and i don't understand why...
i am trying to do something like enter the password and only if it is right you can proceed, then i decided to also put that you can decide to change it and then the password is saved in another file called pass.txt, so this script mainly works with files, but that doesn't matter, what I don't understand is why the compiler tells me there are errors in lines 49, 63, 20 68, try to run it yourself and see if you understand something.
thank you :)

````
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Passwd {
        public static void print(String str) {System.out.println(str);}
        public static void lps(int x) {
                print("wrong password");
                if(x >= 5) {print("last att \n Bye");}
        }
        public static boolean ask(String a, String b) {
                if(a == b) {
                        return true;
                } else {
                        return false;
                }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                try {
                        IOException e = new IOException();
                        File f = new File("pass.txt");
                        FileWriter w = new FileWriter("pass.txt");
                        Scanner ogg = new Scanner(f);
                        print("change password(0) / get access(1): ");
                        int ans = input.nextInt(), n;
                        String pass = ogg.nextLine();
                        if(ans == 0) {
                                while(n <= 5) {
                                        print("password (old): ");
                                        String p1 = input.nextLine();
                                        if(ask(pass, p1)) {
                                               print("new password: ");
                                               String p2 = input.nextLine(), p3 = p2+"aldbd";
                                               while(p2 != p3) {
                                                      print("retype new password: ");
                                                      p3 = input.nextLine();
                                                      if(p2 != p3) {print("the passwords are differents");}
                                               }
                                               w.write(p2);
                                               w.close();
                                               ogg.close();
                                               print("password changed");
                                               break;
                                        } else {
                                               n++;
                                               lps(n);
                                        }
                        } else {
                                while(n <= 5) {
                                        print("old password: ");
                                        String p4 = input.nextLine();
                                        if(ask(pass, p4)) {
                                                print("access garanted");
                                        } else {
                                                n++;
                                                lps(n);
                                        }
                                }
                                w.close();
                                ogg.close();
                        }
                } catch(IOException e) {
                        print("error");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}```
````

Comment: You'd have a better chance of getting help if you specified which errors you're getting. One obvious thing I see in your code that's wrong is how you compare strings, that's not gonna work the way you expect, you should be using `.equals()` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Few things I see wrong:

- you have to import the File class:import java.io.File;
- new FileWriter(...) throws IOException so you have to: add a catch clause, surround with try/catch or add throws IOException to main method. This will fix also the declaration of `new Scanner(f)`;
- you are missing an } to close so this is why you have the problem with "else" function
- also, when you declare the n variable inside the method, you have to initialize it.
- the code can be refactored but let's focus first on solving the errors